# left join cannot access main table fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I want to find the latest `date` from `b.filed` that matches the a.id from table b, and then add this column to the result set.

Table a

[image: table a]

Table b

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Try

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.NAME,
    b.date
FROM
    a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.id = a.id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS b
ON b.id = a.id
```

But my MySQL version is 5.7, which does not support LATERAL, so I used

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.NAME,
    (   SELECT b.date FROM b WHERE a.id = b.id ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS date 
FROM
    a
```

Comment: You can get expected values using max and group by by only querying second table

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: 'The actual situation is that I need to access many b fields, so writing b.field1,b.field2,b.field3 is garbage code' - Question looks oversimplified ,you should publish **representative** sample data

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] PS What is the question?

Comment: [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand which purpose your table A has. In my opinion, it's sufficient to use table B in your query. So this query will do:

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(yourdate) AS date
FROM table_b GROUP BY id,name;
```

Anyway, if you want to join table a, you can do it.

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, MAX(b.yourdate) AS date
FROM table_b AS b JOIN table_a AS a ON a.id=b.id 
GROUP BY b.id,b.name;
```

You can verify here this is also working correctly:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tAkMxHBK)

In the second query, change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` if it's intended to also show those rows from table B whose id DO NOT match the id in table A.